# Protractor @types throwing a lot of errors

Tags: angular, typescript, types, protractor

I am using the Angular2 Webpack Starter by AngularClass and I have recently started running into some errors with protractor and Im not sure where they are coming from.  When I try to build I get the errors:

`Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'IButton'`,
`Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'IKey'`,
`Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Locator'` (about 30 times),
and the same message for the members `IErrorCode`, `IType`, `ILevelValues`, `ILevel`, and a few other members.

I also get the errors:

`Property 'Error' does not exist on type 'typeof error'`

and

`Property 'stacktrace' does not exist on type 'typeof webdriver'`

Just a whole list of errors and Im not sure why they are popping up now or where they are coming from.  Has anyone ran into this or know how to solve this?  Thanks!

Comment: did you run webdriver first before executing protractor

Comment: @MonisMajeed I usually just run `npm start` and the project builds itself so I never deal with webdriver on its own.  Im not sure why these errors are popping up now because I havent changed the way I am doing anything

Comment: Kindly try running the command  webdriver-manager start in your terminal and then check whether you are getting errors

Comment: @MonisMajeed I ran `webdriver-manager start` but it said I needed to update so I ran `webdriver-manager update` which updated it, ran `webdriver-manager start` again which ran and logged `Selenium Server is up and running`, tried `npm start` again but still have the same errors

Comment: Kindly check this http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial

Comment: @MonisMajeed thanks, I went through the tutorial and everything worked fine, not sure what is going on

Comment: @MonisMajeed  Turns out to solve it I had to change my webdriver version (as FriOne suggested below), thanks for the input man, I really appreciate it

Comment: you could also remove the carat from the versions of @types to temporarily fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had the same error, change your version of webdriver `2.44.28`.

`"@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.28",`
and than `npm install`

or

`npm i --save-dev @types/selenium-webdriver@2.44.28`

Comment: thanks for the input, unfortunately that did not work for me

Comment: Did you do npm install after change? I have no errors now.

Comment: yea I did.  You were getting getting a list of like 40 errors in the console before you did this?  And youre using AngularClass webpack-starter?

Comment: Yeah, I modified a little, it may be an npm bug, try to delete node_modules folder and then run npm install again.

Comment: AYYY!! Just tried it again and it worked!  I must have done something wrong initially - thanks man I really appreciate the help!

Comment: This also works if you were getting this error while using the Angular-CLI

Comment: just to clarify, it worked for me when I updated the version in `package.json` and did `npm install`, but not when I updated the version, deleted `node_modules`, then did `npm install` - incase anyone else runs into that problem

Comment: I had the same problem, the recommended solution worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Kind of frustrating amount of time spent before finding this answer. Would expect some indication somewhere that `@types/protractor` needs a certain version of selenium types. Found this (only after finally finding this SO) https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/protractor/package.json where the selenium-webdriver version is specified.

Answer (score 3):

Updating selenium-webdriver to 2.44.28 didn't solve issue for me, but to 2.44.29 - do it)

```
npm i --save @types/selenium-webdriver@2.44.29
```

Working with this environment:

*node -v 5.12.0
npm  -v 3.10.8*

Comment: I had the same problem. 2.44.29 seems to be working for me, but 2.44.28 didn't.

Answer (score 1):

@types/protractor is now a stub, as the package provides its own type definitions. I got rid of all of these errors by running

```
npm uninstall --save @types/protractor
```